# How to start scrollable (overflow-y: scroll) div in the center instead of the top with scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

In my code i have a scrollable div with overflow-y: scroll. The start punt for scrolling is at the top of my div, but i want to start in the center of the div with scrolling. Has anyone a solution for this?

```
export function Portfolio({ children }) {
  const portfolioRef = React.useRef(null)
  return (
    <div ref={portfolioRef} className={styles.component}>
      { children }
    </div>
  )
}

.component {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  height: 30rem;
  margin: auto;

  & > * {
    margin-top: var(--size-xxs);
    margin-bottom: var(--size-xss);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you are having reference to the element , you can use `scrollTop and scrollLeft` functions and assign the value of height , at which position , you want scrollbar to appear

```
//it would be somewhat like this 
useEffect(()=>{
  this.ref.portfolioRef.scrollLeft = 200 //x scroll position
  this.ref.portfolioRef.scrollTop = 200  //y scroll position
 },[])
```

Comment: on which event can i use this?

Comment: on the container element , where scroll is visible, i think as per the code snippet ''.component" is the element , which is scrollable

Comment: No i mean the event for fire the function? Not the element. Because i assume i have to use a function for the scrollTop and scrollLeft?

Comment: if you want to make the scrollbar by default at center, then use componentDidMount/useEffect hook and inside it write the logic of moving the scrollbar

Comment: Are these numbers in px? can you use %?

Comment: i guess not in %, but still you can give a shot , and verify